# How to bind dynamic data with pie chart using jason ajax in MVC C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, pie-chart

How to bind dynamic data with pie chart using jason ajax in c#

My requirement is to bind dynamic data with pie chart.
So using jason ajax I got the record from database using below code.

```
$(function () {
    debugger
    $("#btnApply").click(function () {
        var jsonInputParams = {}
        //jsonInputParams["Year"] = $('#Year').val() === '' ? null : $('#Year').val().split('/')[1] + '/' + $('#Year').val().split('/')[0] + '/' + $('#Year').val().split('/')[2];
        jsonInputParams["Year"] = '1/1/2018';
        jsonInputParams["SupplierId"] = 2;
        ajaxUtil.AjaxReq("/AjaxHandler/Base.aspx/ExecuteOperation", "{'jsonStringObject': '" + JSON.stringify(jsonInputParams) + "','procedure':'UspGetGraphData'}", getGraphReqCallBack)
       

    });
    function getGraphReqCallBack(data) {
        debugger
        var data= JSON.parse(data)
     var GradeName = data[0];
        var WeightLoaded = parseInt(data[1]);
        var InvoiceAmount = data[2];
       
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market shares in March, 2022',
                align: 'left'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            accessibility: {
                point: {
                    valueSuffix: '%'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },

            series: [{
                
                name: 'BAc',
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [{
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: test,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                }, {
                    name: 'Edge',
                    y: 12.82
                }, {
                    name: 'Firefox',
                    y: 4.63
                }, {
                    name: 'Safari',
                    y: 2.44
                }, {
                    name: 'Internet Explorer',
                    y: 2.02
                }, {
                    name: 'Other',
                    y: 3.28
                }]
            }]
        });
    };
});
```

When I am trying to add  GradeName, WeightLoaded, InvoiceAmount data with pie chart I got the error.
I have tried to solve this error and I found that data came up with csv format, so pie chart is not accepted.

So first I need to transfer csv file in datatable or array list [I am not sure], and after that I need to assign array value with pie chart.

But I dont know how I  should convert csv to array list or datatable at client side.

```
var _data = JSON.parse(data)
var _chartLabels = _data[0];
var _chartData = _data[1];
```

Added this code with chart

```
data: {
  labels: _chartLabels,
  datasets: [
    {                           
      data: _chartData
    }
  ]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016562/parse-csv-records-in-to-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript ?